# How to get words that end with certain characters within each string r

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I have a vector of strings that looks like:

```
str <- c("bills slashed for poor families today", "your calls are charged", "complaints dept awaiting refund")
```

I want to get all the words that end with the letter `s` and remove the `s`. I have tried:

```
gsub("s$","",str)
```

but it doesn't work because it tries to match with the strings that end with `s` instead of words. I'm trying to get an output that looks like:

```
[1] bill slashed for poor familie today
[2] your call are charged
[3] complaint dept awaiting refund
```

Any pointers as to how I can do this? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$` checks for the end of the string, not the end of a word.

To check for the word boundaries you should use `\b`

So:

```
gsub("s\\b", "", str)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a non base R solution:

```
library(rebus)
library(stringr)

plurals <- "s" %R% BOUNDARY
str_replace_all(str, pattern = plurals, replacement = "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a positive lookahead assertion:

```
gsub(pattern = "s{1}(?>\\s)", " ", x = str, perl = T)
```

I am no expert on regex, but I believe this expression looks for an "s" if it is followed by a space.  Finding a match, it replaces that "s" with a space.  So, final "s's" are removed.

Comment: Note that this would not catch an s at the end of the string, you should add `|s$` at the end to allow that (or, well, use `\b`...).